# Failed to decrypt keystore, invalid store password or store password not supplied - BlackBerry Signing Error

Tags: blackberry-10, keystore

My Android Runtime Apk converted Bar file is on BB World Store. I am in process of updating new release for my existing app on store. I am using **BlackBerry Apk Packager** tool to sign and deploy the app on store. My bar file is generated successfully, after generating bar file it is aking for keystore password, when I type my password it is saying,

> Signing failed. Do you want to run signing configuration now?

In output window, its showing below error:

> Failed to decry-pt keystore, invalid store password or store password
>   not supplied.

I have my token file and p12 file in the following locations:

```
C:\Users\PcName\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\bbidtoken.csk

C:\Users\PcName\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\author.p12
```

How to get new keystore password? If I reset my keystore password, won't I be able to update my existing app on store?

Answer (score 0):

If you were the person that created the keystore, you could try recreating it with the password you want to use. Java Keytool is an option for generating keystores with certificates you have.

For example:

```
\CommonFiles\OpenJDK\bin>keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore <your cert> -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore <your keystore>
-deststoretype JKS
Enter destination keystore password:
Enter source keystore password:

Entry for alias <your alias> successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
```